# NATS api for creating clusters and gateways

Tags: nats.io, nats-streaming-server

Does NATS provide some api for managing its topology, i e create new cluster, combine it in supercluster, create gateway etc.
In docs I see only file configuration, but is there another way for configuring nats?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no API to handle topology.
Leveraging gossip protocol should ease the process - when adding a new node to the cluster, you don't need to alter the configuration of the current ones, nor let clients know.

https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/nats_admin/upgrading_cluster